# Canvas context setTransform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

### Problem when rendering a tranformed image to a canvas:

```
base_image.src = temp.src;

var matrix = temp.style.msTransform;
matrix = matrix.replace("matrix(", "");
matrix = matrix.replace(")", "");
var array = matrix.split(",");
base_image.onload = function () {
   canvasCtx.save();
   canvasCtx.setTransform(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5]);
   canvasCtx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
   canvasCtx.restore();
}
```

---

The problem only happens when i rotate or scale the image.. when it's not rotated or scaled it is transfered at the exact position as it was as an image above the canvas.. BUT when i rotate or scale it is not at the right position. always some pixels to the right/left and sime pixels to top/bottom. always shifted and it depends of how much i scaled or rotated.
How to fix it?
Thanks,
Alan.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: It sounds like you've missed the other 2 important steps. If you want to rotate or scale _in-place_, then you need to do 3 steps, not just 1. First translate it so that the center of the image is above the origin (0,0) then rotate/scale, next translate by the same amount and the opposite direction than you did in step 1. See here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/transformation.html

Comment: Multiply the scaled value to the transform matrix,